# Using isset with mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, isset

I'm really new to PHP and am trying to build a log in system. I am aware it's really insecure, but it is just a college project in understanding the basics of PHP, so for now that's not a problem.

I have my usernames and passwords in a table and I am trying to store a cookie if the user types in the correct username and password combination. I want to have pages that can only be accessed if the user is logged in.

I keep getting the Undefined Index notice. I am aware from this article http://notesofgenius.com/how-fix-php-notice-undefined-index/ that I need to add isset somewhere, but I can't work out where to put it in my code. Using isset with mysql_real_escape_string is confusing me.

I've connected to the database and started the session in config.php. Here is the code:

```
<?php

require("config.php");
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);   
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users
WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'
"
    );
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$_SESSION['user'] = 'Person';
header('Location: postarticle.php');
}
else{
echo "<p>Incorrect password</p>";
}
?>
```

Thanks. Apologies if this has been asked before, I did check but couldn't find anything.

Comment: [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) should be [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli-real-escape-string)

Comment: you wrote you want use cookie but you use $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `isset()` has nothing to do with escaping. There is no connection between these 2 facilities.

Also, isset() won't make your code working if it doesn't. It can save you an error message in case you are calling this page regular way, without sending a form to it. 
But if you keep getting this message with form sent - check form `method` and input `name` attributes.

Anyway, you don't actually need `isset()` here

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    require("config.php");
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = 'Person';
        header('Location: postarticle.php');
        exit;

    } else {

        echo "<p>Incorrect password</p>";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code:

```
require("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
  // your other code in here
}
```

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks whether a variable is set and not null. The error you're getting now is probably because the login form is being submitted when either the `username` or `password` inputs are empty.

Also, if you want to use `$_SESSION` then you should add [`session_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) just before `$_SESSION['user'] = 'Person';`.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it sorted now.